# How to "intersect" or "refine" a pair of abstract simplicial complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, simplicial-complexes

Let $S,T$ be abstract simplicial complexes.

> Is there a (unique) abstract simplicial complex that gives me the most of what is in common with $S$ and $T$?

I'm thinking of this as an "intersection," or "refinement" of the two complexes, maybe a "core" that has the most properties of both. I could take the trivial simplicial complex on the smaller number of vertices of the two, but this misses larger simplices. Better, I could take the largest simplicial complex $A$ smaller than both $S$ and $T$ for which there are injective simplicial maps $A\to S$ and $A\to T$, sort of as [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126575/combinatorial-distance-between-simplicial-complexes). But this is not unique:

[image]

$A$ and $B$ can't be compared by set inclusion. I can't think of any "good" construction of such an intersection, I can't capture all the similarities. For example, there is a simplicial map $A\to B$ that is injective on 1-simplices, but no such map $B\to A$, so $A$ could be considered "smaller" than $B$. But this seems roundabout. I'd be glad for any insight into why such a construction can / cannot work.

Maybe I should look in a different category or use a different construction? Move to homology? My larger goal is to build a constructible sheaf valued in simplicial complexes. I know what its value should be at every stalk (some simplicial complex), but I'm not sure how I should be defining the sheaf on larger open sets that intersect several strata.

Comment: It looks like this would depend a lot on what structure you are trying to preserve. For example, does the number of edges matter? Would a graph consisting of two vertices and one edge, and the graph consisting of three vertices and two edges, be the same?

Comment: @YosemiteSam Yes, number of edges matters.The ones you mentioned would be $\{a,b,\{a,b\}\}$ and $\{a,b,c,\{a,b\},\{b,c\}\}$. I would consider the "intersection" of these two to be the first one, since it is a subset / simplicial subcomplex of the second. I am trying to preserve as many simplices as possible that both have (maybe a "largest possible" subcomplex both have).